# Cordova app lagging in android device

Tags: android, performance, cordova

I tried creating a cordova app and importing 2048 game code into it. Here's the link to that code : https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048.

I have just copy pasted the entire contents from index.html and imported other css and js files.
The problem is that app works fine in iOS device but the scroll lags a lot in android device.
I tried to find some solutions like fastclick script but could not see any result. (Crosswalk is the solution but it increases app size so need an alternative solution)
Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have Created iOS and Android build on real device using given source code(https://github.com/gabrielecirulli/2048). Not find any type of scroll lags in android device. Is there any specific scenario explain in deatils.